# blender python script on headless master/slave nodes for a rendering farm setup

Tags: python, rendering, blender

Does any one ever tried to write a functional error free python script for firing up a master or slave headless blender rendering node?
I use

```
import bpy
import os
import time
import netrender
from netrender.utils import *
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.engine = "NET_RENDER"
/* for master */
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].network_render.mode = "RENDER_MASTER"
/* for slave */
py.data.scenes["Scene"].network_render.mode = "RENDER_SLAVE"
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].network_render.server_address = "10.11.12.13"

/* then */
bpy.ops.render.netclientstart()
```

IT WORKS :)

Now I must add parameter parsing from system shell, I am bored atm LOL

Comment: [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8405/935) explains passing cli arguments to your blender script.